# Having multiple equality conditionals for NumPy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, conditional-statements

Say I have a large 2D numpy array (call it **A**) that contains integers from 0 to 9.

I am trying to write a function that returns a binary NumPy array (call it **B**) of the same shape as **A** that has the following features.

An entry in **B** is 1 if the corresponding element in **A** appears in a given list **L**; otherwise, the entry is zero.

Below shows what probably is not the most efficient code for doing this.

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 5))
L = [3,4,5]

B = np.zeros(A.shape)
for e in L:
    B[A==e] = 1
```

Is there a faster way ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like it falls to me to point out the obvious:

```
def AinL(A, L):
    B = np.zeros((10,), int)
    B[L] = 1
    return B[A]
```

Benchmarks:

```
 10x10 #L=3
orig     0.6665631101932377
HAL      0.4370500799268484
Psidom   1.13961720908992
PP       0.23527960386127234

 100x100 #L=3
orig     0.3015591569710523
HAL      0.29902734607458115
Psidom   0.4470538650639355
PP       0.18963343487121165

 1000x1000 #L=4
orig     0.5516874771565199
HAL      0.5967503408901393
Psidom   0.6331975681241602
PP       0.23225238709710538

 10000x1000 #L=2
orig     0.8539429588709027
HAL      0.9840140701271594
Psidom   1.0392512339167297
PP       0.7203555379528552
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two `numpy` options with `np.in1d` which is a vectorized version of `in` from base python. When the array is large, the first option shows some speed up:

*Option one (fast one)*:

```
np.in1d(A, L).reshape(A.shape).astype(int)
```

*Option two (slow one)*:

```
np.apply_along_axis(np.in1d, 0, A, L).astype(int)
```

*Timing*:

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 10, (1000, 1000))
L = [3,4,5]
​
def loop():
    B = np.zeros(A.shape)
    for e in L:
        B[A==e] = 1
    return B

%timeit np.in1d(A, L).reshape(A.shape).astype(int)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 6.4 ms per loop

%timeit loop()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 16.8 ms per loop

%timeit np.apply_along_axis(np.in1d, 1, A, L).astype(int)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 21.5 ms per loop

%timeit np.apply_along_axis(np.in1d, 0, A, L).astype(int)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 35.1 ms per loop
```

*Result checking*:

```
B1 = loop()
B2 = np.apply_along_axis(np.in1d, 0, A, L).astype(int)
B3 = np.apply_along_axis(np.in1d, 1, A, L).astype(int)
B4 = np.in1d(A, arrL).reshape(A.shape).astype(int)

(B1 == B2).all()
# True

(B1 == B3).all()
# True

(B1 == B4).all()
# True
```

Comment: My timing results provided a different narrative. I'm using python 3.5 and numpy 1.10.4 from anaconda, and the original loop is roughly 3 times faster than using in1d. EDIT: I see now that you used a 1000x1000 random matrix. I will retest with the same sized matrix.

Comment: @HAL9001 I just tested on python 3 as well, I am getting pretty consistent result. The first np.in1d option is faster. How large is the array you are testing?

Comment: Psidom's results were confirmed when using 1000x1000.

Answer (score 2):

Using @Psidom's 1000x1000 matrix, I introduced two other methods, and included the `np.in1d` method that @Psidom provided.

One uses an iterative sum, the other an iterative bitwise or.

The iterative bitwise or, `trial2()`, proves itself below, providing a result that is roughly 4 times faster than the original, and 2 times faster than numpy's in3d, however note that it provides a matrix result that is of boolean type.

When the bitwise method is modified to return an integer result, `trial2_int()`, its speed is basically equivalent to numpy's `in1d`.

```
A = np.random.randint(0,10,(1000,1000))
L = [3,4,5]
def original():
  B = np.zeros(A.shape)
  for e in L:
      B[A==e] = 1
  return B

def trial1():
  B = np.empty(A.shape)
  for e in L:
    B += A == e
  return B

def trial2():
  B = A==L[0]
  for e in L[1:]:
    B |= A == e
  return B

def trial2_int():
  B = trial2()
  return B.astype(int)

def trial_Psidom():
  B = np.in1d(A,L).reshape(A.shape).astype(int)
  return B
```

Results:

```
%timeit original()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 10.5 ms per loop
%timeit trial1()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 9.43 ms per loop
%timeit trial2()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 2.37 ms per loop
%timeit trial2_int()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 5.31 ms per loop
%timeit trial_Psidom()
# 100 loops, best of 3: 5.37 ms per loop
```

Comment: If `L` is small relative to `A`, `np.in1d` does a raveled version of your `trial2` - iterate on `L` and use `B|=...`.